# How to create a relay server with gstreamer?

Tags: java, gstreamer

I know how I can accept a stream from my webcam and display it inside a swing component:

```
args = Gst.init("VideoTest", args);
    pipe = new Pipeline("VideoTest");
    final Element videosrc = ElementFactory.make("v4l2src", "source");
    final Element videofilter = ElementFactory.make("capsfilter", "filter");
    videofilter.setCaps(Caps.fromString("video/x-raw-yuv, width=640, height=480"
            + ", bpp=32, depth=32, framerate=30/1"));
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            VideoComponent videoComponent = new VideoComponent();
            Element videosink = videoComponent.getElement();
            pipe.addMany(videosrc, videofilter, videosink);
            Element.linkMany(videosrc, videofilter, videosink);

            // Now create a JFrame to display the video output
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swing Video Test");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(videoComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            videoComponent.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(720, 576));
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);

            // Start the pipeline processing
            pipe.setState(State.PLAYING);
        }
    });
```

What I'd like to do now would be to make this stream available for each client which will connect to a certain port using, for example, vlc media player or another video stream reader. This would have to be generic, that is I may want to connect another gstreamer program too and make this program a relay server: it is client for the first one and makes this stream available for other clients.

Is there a way to do this? I am still new to gstreamer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually quite straightforward using RTPbin, but first you'll want to encode your video because sending raw YUV will take an enormous amount of bandwidth.

Here is an example pipeline using h263 encoding and RTP bin:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtpbin name=rtpbin \
        v4l2src ! videoconvert ! ffenc_h263 ! rtph263ppay ! rtpbin.send_rtp_sink_0 \
                  rtpbin.send_rtp_src_0 ! udpsink port=5000                            \
                  rtpbin.send_rtcp_src_0 ! udpsink port=5001 sync=false async=false    \
                  udpsrc port=5005 ! rtpbin.recv_rtcp_sink_0                           \
```

More information here (including how to receive this data on the other end):
http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-rtpbin.html

Comment: I tried opening it with vlc but is says "demux: cannot peek"..moreover ffenc_h263 doesn't exist and I had to use avenc_h263

Comment: avenc_h263 is the equivalent ffmpeg encoder plugin for gstreamer 1.x.  Apologies for the incorrect pipeline.  It sounds like VLC doesn't know how to handle a raw h263 stream since the error you'r seeing comes from the demuxer and you're not even sending muxed content. Did you try playing the stream with gstreamer?  If you can play it in GST but not VLC, you may need to wrap your h263 stream in a transport stream as well.